# Maxima CAS in emacs : change line wrap settings or disabling line wrap in the output

Tags: maxima, word-wrap

I'm using text mode maxima in emacs. Is there a way to change the character limit for line wrapping or disable line wrapping of equations entirely in the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set [linel](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/maxima_4.html#linel)

```
(%i7) makelist(42, i, 30);
(%o7) [42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 
                                42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42]
(%i8) linel: 200;
(%o8)                                                                                             200
(%i9) makelist(42, i, 30);
(%o9)                                   [42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42]
```